# Do I create separate activities or do I write all the code on one?

Tags: android

I am really new to coding and would like to ask a question. I grabbed some code from mkyongs website and would like to know something. The code has a button that changes an image to a different image. I would like to have 2 buttons that changes the image. First button changes the image to a different image, second button changes that image again. I would like to know if I create a new activity and use all the same code or if I attach the onClickListener again on the same activity. Thanks :)

Here is the code for the button and image change (Activity)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity2 extends Activity {

    Button button;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.background3);


            }


        });

    }



}
```

Comment: You can add a new button to the same activity. Have you gone through the basics of android before picking this code from some site. I suggest you start with some tutorials here and then you will not ask this question.

Comment: You don't need second activity. What for?  same code you will use if your second activity will do exactly same work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are trying to Swipe images, the below example is from this [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm)

They created 2 methos (next and previous) on the same activity, that will the images

```
 public void next(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next Image", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
      android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
      Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
      android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
      imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
      imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
      imageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   }
   public void previous(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "previous Image", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
      android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
      Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
      android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
      imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(out);
      imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(in);
      imageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   }
```

However it seems your new to android Development so I recomend to read the basics and try them first , there are hundreds of tutorials on the internet just google. You can start from [android site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)